# How do you identify (but not fix) values in csv file that are nulls or duplicates using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file

I'm quite new to programming and I'm not sure how to go about simply identifying duplicate records and null values in a csv file using a simple python program. I don't want to fix them, I just want to identify them. I have asked questions involving similar before and people gave me answers involving the pandas module, but I'm afraid that is a little above me at the moment so I would be grateful if people would give me answers not involving pandas, as it won't really help me!
Here's the code, and sorry if it makes you want to cry about it's poor quality and (hopefully not) irrelevant nature of it, but I'm really stuck so it's the best I could do on my own.

```
with open('testdata1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for row in csv_reader:
    if not row[0]:
         continue
```

It's not much, but I'm lost and need a fair bit of help.
Many thanks

Comment: I think learning pandas is easier than analyzing data at this level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just clarifying, the below code is not necessarily the optimal way to do this, and there are multiple ways. However, as you seem to be early on in your python career I'm going to try to explain the concepts.

You already have the start of how to do this in your code. The line:

```
if not row[0]:
```

Is checking if the first element in the row evaluates to `True` or `False`. In this case, because of the `not`, a value of `True` will not pass while a value of `False` will. Try checking out [this page, specifically 4.4 and 4.10](https://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch04.html).

Your variable `row` is a list that you can iterate through. I'm going to make a slight modification to your code, just to give the index as you loop through the rows:

```
# Using enumerate() returns the index, too.
# So the first row will have i=0, the second i=1 etc. 
for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
    # Now you can loop through each item in the row itself
    for j, item in enumerate(row):
        # Now for your logic to check if it's null
        if not item:
            # This will print the row number, the column number, and the item
            # should it not pass the check.
            print(f"Item in row {i + 1} and column {j + 1} is: {item}")
```

Now, if you follow the above link, you'll see in section 4.10 that a value of `0` will also cause this to print, so you might need to amend this logic depending on what you need. I would encourage you to iterate on this and find the logic that works for you, but some additional points are:

- You can check the type of a variable using `type()`. Check what `type(item)` would give for different cases in your csv.
- You can use the above in `if` statements, e.g. `if type(1) == int:`
- Nulls will likely be represented by an empty string `""`, so you could check `if item == "":`

Checking for duplicates would be a bit harder, and you'll likely have to keep a record of what you've already seen, but you can check if something is already in another list by using `in`, e.g.:

```
1 in [1, 2, 3]
>>> True

4 in [1, 2, 3]
>>> False

# You can check lists, too
[1, 2] in [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
>>> True

[1, 4] in [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
>>> False
```

So you might want to keep track of each row you've seen in a new list, and for each row check if it's already in that list. Something that tracks the duplicate rows could be:

```
seen_rows = []
duplicate_rows = []
for row in csv_reader:
    # If the row is already in seen_rows, add it to duplicate_rows
    if row in seen_rows:
        duplicate_rows.append(row)
    # If not, add it to seen_rows so you can check future rows against it.
    else:
        seen_rows.append(row)
```

I know you have addressed this in your question, but pandas would make this easier. I think you're right to try and understand the fundamentals first, but in pandas this would be a simple:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('testdata1.csv')
# This would select the rows that have any null values in them.
null_rows = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]

# This would select rows that are duplicates
duplicate_rows = df[df.duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Say, You made the 2d array, matrix, each sell contains a value - 0 or float or int number.

```
array = [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
for i in range(0,len(array)):
    for j in range(1,len(array[i])):
        if array[i][j] == array[i][j-1]:
            #element is duplicated
            print('duplicate',i,j)
        elif array[i][j] == 0:

            print('null',i,j)
```

Hope this will help You. For more advanced techniques it's better to use pandas.